# memcpy() hangs in __memcpy_neon when copying into DMA buffer

Tags: linux, arm, memcpy, neon, dma

I am cyclically filling the mmap-ed DMA buffer with my data by copying it from "normal" memory in 290 bytes chunks.

At the first cycle `memcpy` always passes OK. At the second cycle it hangs in `__memcpy_neon` (at least this is what the gdb says each time when I press Ctrl-C).

Disassembler always shows the `strmi` instruction been stuck in.

Just for test purpose I substituted `memcpy()` with my simple byte-byte `memcpy1()` and everything works fine on all 3MB DMA buffer (but slower obviously...:-)). To exclude the alignment issue I tested library `memcpy()`to copy unaligned buffers - no problems detected.

I am using `linux 2.6.37` with `glibc 2.23 (gcc 6.3.1 linaro)` on `DM8148` CPU.

Why this memcpy hangs in general and for the second time particularly?

UPDATE: After tons of experiments with different assembler variants of memcpy I can say that what hangs is the NEON memory copy instructions, both with and without preload:

```
Loop:
  PLD [r1, #0xC0]
  VLDM r1!,{d0-d7}
  VSTM r0!,{d0-d7}
  SUBS r2,r2,#0x40
  BNE Loop
```

All other "normal" variants of memcpy() work fine.
Are there any mysteries in using DMA uncached(!) mmaped memory with NEON instructions?

Comment: Can you explain why you have two memcpy ? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: @Stoogy I believe the sources are [here](https://github.molgen.mpg.de/git-mirror/glibc/blob/glibc-2.23/sysdeps/arm/armv7/multiarch/memcpy_impl.S) for that memcpy.

Comment: @Stoogy not sure what you mean. There is the endless loop of copying from my data source to the DMA buffer. The library memcpy() hangs on the second cycle. When I use simply byte-byte copy, everything works fine - which means that there is no problem of boundaries, mapping or something similar.

Comment: You should check the addresses if they are aligned to 8. If you cannot guarantee this alignment, you should use the `vld1.8` and `vst1.8` instructions instead.

Comment: @ Jake 'Alquimista' LEE, thank you. Yes, I need to check this, but do I need to check the arguments passed to the C-library memcpy() function?!?!

Comment: @leonp typecast the memory pointer to a `uint32_t` variable, and check if the value is a multiple of 8.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the answer is "yes! there are mysteries in using DMA uncached(!) mmaped memory with NEON instructions". As ARM manual states, "Cortex A8 supports unaligned memory access. However unaligned access to strongly ordered memory is not supported"
As the DMA buffer is most probably strongly ordered memory, the glibc memcpy using NEON fails when accessing this DMA memory. It happens in my case on the second cycle, because the first access was aligned, while the second was not.

Comment: If you have any control over this try not to use strongly ordered memory (or device memory) unless you really need to. You can use uncached "normal" memory for most DMA use cases, which allows unaligned access.

Comment: I don't really understand what s "strongly ordered" memory. 
My DMA buffers are in the ordinary DDR, which I see in Linux in "Virtual kernel memory Layout" as "DMA". I receive this memory using dma_alloc_coherent().
Please, comment...:-)

Comment: Try using `dma_alloc_writecombine()`, but note that this will start to use the CPU write buffer, so you'll need to call `dma_wmb()` to ensure that the writebuffer is drained before you kick off any access on another piece of hardware.

Comment: @solidpixel thank you for the lesson - really interesting, didn't know.
To my pity I can't use `dma_wmb()` - all runs in the user space. But it is very useful knowledge.
Meanwhile, I ended with Android version of `memcpy()` with slight change of 16 bytes per chunk to 64...:-) This version uses pre-alignment code...